# Play 2.5+ and CacheAPI

Tags: playframework

I am using Play 2.5.4. I just started using the CacheAPI to store the currently logged in user because it is needed multiple times over a page request. I added this object to cache, via cache.set(). I have this working just fine.

The problem is, if I update this user object to have different permissions or roles from an administrator's account, I need to invalidate that cache object for that user so that user can get the proper permissions or roles.

How can I accomplish updating the cache for a user? 
How can I do that across multiple web servers?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How do you cache User? Wthat'w the key of this cache?..

Comment: I am caching via cache.set() and cache.get() in Play, which uses EHCache under the hood. I store the user's ID (primary key) in session when a user logs in, then retrieve from cache that user object via a cache key using that user's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I accomplish updating the cache for a user?

You just add it again. Supposing you are using the user id as the key

```
cache.set(user.getId(), user);
```

> How can I do that across multiple web servers?

Now this is a completely different question. Play by default uses EhCache as the cache provider, and Play Cache api does not create a distributed cache by default.

I don't have much knowlegde with EhCache, but I think it supports a distributed cache (ie a cache between multiple servers) in a different product, and it also supports replication. So you may want to investigate that first and see if it suit you.

You can also create your implementation of the [Cache API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache#Custom-implementations), and use EhCache/Terracota/Memcached/HazelCast to provide the setup you need.

Another option is for you to use something like Akka Clustering/PubSub extension and deal with the cache invalidation (ie: invalidate a cache in server 1 --> broadcast message for every server to invalidate that cache also). Unless you are comfortable with Akka and PubSub extension this probably will be difficult to implement.

As a last resort, if you can afford that, you can just set the cache with some short expiration time (ex: 1 minute). This is the easiest way if you can afford that your application sees an outdated object for the expiration time, at most

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have my one-server instance of cache working, using session to hold that's user's key, and cache to retrieve the user object via the key in session. session.put("USER_ID", user.id)... then later retrieve from cache.get("CACHED_USER" + sessiong.get("USER_ID"))... something along those lines, but I check for nulls, etc. Since Play uses EHCache, I will check into the clustered implementation of EHCache. Thanks again for the help.